# Record number of keystrokes per hour

Tags: time-management, mouse, keyboard

I need to record numbers of keystrokes and mouse clicks per hour for my own record keeping.
(09:00~10:00, 10:00~11:00, ..., 17:00~18:00 etc)

I don't need to keep what key I typed, but just need only total number of keystrokes.
Please exclude WhatPulse.

Is there a good software or appropricate C/C++, Java, or Python code to implement it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the KeyCounter app; to build out a list of only the keys you want to count, auto-save and reload your key list and counts, export the current list, and counts on CSV format. You can download it by following this link http://skwire.dcmembers.com/apps/keycounter/KeyCounter.zip

You can also try [Keystroke Counter and Frequency Recorder Software](https://www.sobolsoft.com/keystrokecounter/download/setup.exe) (count the keys and words typed while working).

If you want to record your keystrokes you can use [Best Free Keylogger](https://bestxsoftware.com/). It can be used to monitor any employee's computer and generates reports of their daily activities.